# Trouble using sed/regex to remove last character in string

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to remove a trailing " from all lines in a CSV. I am using RedHat Linux.

I'm able to do it successfully in VIM doing `%s/"$//g`

However, doing `sed -e 's/"$//g'` does not work (both in the terminal, and when I have it as part of a bash script). A similar call that I make to remove LEADING " from all the lines, `sed -e 's/^"//g'` DOES work, so I am extremely confused! Especially since it works in VIM.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `sed  's/" *$//'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yup, but I don't have trailing whitespace. I also checked in VIM to see if I have the carriage return right after the ". Definitely weird behavior...

Comment: did you check the contents of the file before running the sed command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your file is in `DOS` format. Try like this:

```
$ cat file
line1"
line2"
line3"
$ sed -e 's/"$//' file
line1"
line2"
line3"
$ sed -e $'s/"[\r]\\?$//' file
line1
line2
line3
$
```

To check if the file is in `DOS` format, you can:

```
$ file file
file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ head -n 1 file | hexdump -C
00000000  6c 69 6e 65 31 22 0d 0a                   |line1"..|
00000008
$
```

There are tools like `dos2unix` (and `unix2dos`) which you can use to convert it if necessary.

`Vim` is much smarter in dealing with different format of files so it's not surprised `vim` can handle it as expected.

Comment: Wow! That did the trick! And normally VIM displays end of lines as ^M, hinting at the \r, so that is interesting.. Thanks :)